# Next Business Day after 15th Bash Script

Tags: shell

I need bash script for next business day after 15th of the current month. It should only give me next business day after 15th. I'm totally new to Bash Script. Thanks a lot.
`d=1
while (($(date -d "$d days" +%u) >= 6)); do ((++d)); done
date -d "$d days" +%m/%d/%Y`

Comment: I tried this script but I get next business day. I need next business day after 15th of current month. 
d=1
while (($(date -d "$d days" +%u) >= 6)); do ((++d)); done
date -d "$d days" +%m/%d/%Y

Comment: Ok so, drop what you have tried into your question and you'll be more likely to get an answer...

Comment: I have tried this script as well but I'm not getting business day. date -d "15 day -$(($(date +"%d")-1)) days" +"%m/%d/%Y"

Comment: Actually, you first script outputs 01/29/2013, which is the next business day after the 15th of this month...

Comment: I only need next business day after 15th. 
Ex: if 15th was on Saturday then I should get Monday's date. It doesnt matter which day I run the script, I should get next business day after 15th of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty using cal:
First case is Friday, then Saturday, then Sunday.

```
( cal | grep -q "15 16$"  && echo 18  ) || ( cal | grep -q "15$"  && echo 17  ) || (  echo 16 )
```