# How to schedule the job in cron which will run every month of 8th business day

Tags: linux, unix

I want to schedule a job which will run 8th business day of every month. How can i achieve it.

Format :

30 1 * 1-12 1 [Command]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568400/next-business-day-after-15th-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this as a daily cron this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f ./ranThisMonth ]; then
    if [ "$(date +%d -gt 10)" ]; then
        rm ./ranThisMonth.tmp
    fi
else
    echo "Running now!"
    if [[ "$(date +%u)" -lt 5 && "$(date +%d)" -ge 8 ]]; then

        # Your commands here

        touch ./ranThisMonth.tmp
    fi
fi
```

1. `if [ -f ./ranThisMonth ]; then` checks whether it ran the current month
2. `if [ "$(date +%d -gt 10)" ]; then` in case its past the 10th resets it
3. `if [[ "$(date +%u)" -lt 5 && "$(date +%d)" -ge 8 ]]; then` if weekday (businessday) and past the 8th